# Sorting an array list with a delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, delimiter

I have been stuck on this problem for so long and i have no idea what to do. 
Basically i have a text file with people names then student number then prize money like this:

```
Green%3243%1000
Kevin%7657%400
Frank%345%10000
Bob%5435%5000
Stefan%31231%1000
Javis%4532%100
IronMan%5435%2000
Lamp%534%3000
```

What i want to be able to do is sort the array based on the last number.

I tried this abomination (Don't bother reading it its garbage):

```
    boolean flag = true;
    String temp;
    int temp1;
    int temp2;

    while (flag){
        flag = false;
        for(int j=0;  j < list.size() -1;  j++ ){
            System.out.println(list.get(j));
            Scanner s = new Scanner(list.get(j)).useDelimiter("%");
            s.next();
            s.next();
            temp1 = s.nextInt();
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(list.get(j+1)).useDelimiter("%");
            s2.next();
            s2.next();
            temp2 = s2.nextInt();
            if (temp1 < temp2){
                temp = list.get(j);
                list.add(j, list.get(j+1));
                list.add(j+1,temp);
                flag = true;
            } 
        } 
    }
```

But its just infinitely looping. My though while making it was just patching array lists into a bubble sort.

If anyone has any ideas and is willing to share them it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is an object-oriented language, so I'll just use objects:

- Create a `Student` object with the three values you want to store (and a `toString()` method to print them separated by "%":

  ```
  public class Student {
      private final String name;
      private final int number;
      private final int prizeMoney;

      public Student(final String name, final int number, final int prizeMoney) {
          this.name = name;
          this.number = number;
          this.prizeMoney = prizeMoney;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return name+"%"+number+"%"+prizeMoney;
      }

      public int getPrizeMoney() {
          return prizeMoney;
      }
  }
  ```
- Read your lines as `Student` objects, and store them in a `List`:

  ```
  final Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/StudentsList"));
  final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();    

  while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
      final Scanner line = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
      line.useDelimiter("%");

      students.add(new Student(line.next(), line.nextInt(), line.nextInt()));

      line.close();
  }
  scan.close();
  ```
- Order the `List` with a custom `Comparator`, and print it:

  ```
  students.sort(new Comparator<Student>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(final Student s1, final Student s2) {
          return s1.getPrizeMoney()-s2.getPrizeMoney();
      }
  });

  for (final Student student: students)
      System.out.println(student);
  ```

**Output**:

```
Javis%4532%100
Kevin%7657%400
Green%3243%1000
Stefan%31231%1000
IronMan%5435%2000
Lamp%534%3000
Bob%5435%5000
Frank%345%10000
```

Comment: This seems like it would  be the right answer however i am no where near a skill level to be able to use that code. I tried it and i got errors everywhere mostly because i didn't know what to do with it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Kevin What are the errors you got ? You have to put the `Student` class, in its own file (called Student.java), and do something with the `FileNotFoundException` that can be thrown when you create the new `Scanner`, otherwise it should work just by copying-pasting it.

Comment: I have no idea what was wrong with it, i did everything you said, not to be ungrateful for all the work you put into this (it looks like alot) however someone else suggested using three dimensional arrays to do it so that is what i am going to try. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Kevin If you are still interested, I put the two full files online at http://pastebin.com/BrR0c9q0 and http://pastebin.com/6x9Kiqaw ; the things you may want to change are the package name and the path to the student list file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something for you to get head started.

1. Create a map for prize money => line as key/value pair
2. Read each line in the file, parse it and put key/value pair in the above map
3. Once your map is ready, convert the keys entry set into the collections like list
4. Sort the collections, using Collections.sort()
5. Iterate over the created map, and for each value in the collection get the corresponding value from the map.

Hope this helps you to get the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Id consider creating a 3d array here 8x8x8 from right to left in the array is row, col, and in so [0][0][1] is block one or kevin [0][1][1] is 7657 [1][1][1] is 400. I like this way because not only does it give each 'item' an array it allows you to keep it organized and easily accessable

Comment: This seems like a really good way of doing it but i have no idea how to do it, I've been trying for a while but I've been having no luck. Care to help?

Comment: Yeah no problem, although i have no used the scanner class in a while. I am aware that it is an extension class for System.in() which is actually javas native input class which is why Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in()) I will add another answer shortly. However a few things, Explain step by step how you think this should be done. Are you looking to become a software engineer?

Comment: Im dreaming to get this assignment done right now, but i have no idea how to set up the loops for this. AS i was typing this i though of something, i will post back if it works.

Comment: How i think this should be done is how you said in the initial answer, so i need a loop through every index assigning each one to a part of the list, i might use the split("%") instead of delimiters but i don't under stand how to set up the loops to accomplish this. i was thinking 3 nested for loops but that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah no i was too, and what slipped over my head was one type is String and the other two are ints, We cant store any other types than String in a string array or ints in a int array. While(nextLine())//Supposed to be a Boolean value that reports if there is any more tokens. In that body just make 3 arrays but keep them aligned so read name store, increment row, read middle int store, iterate column, read next value, store, then increment z value. This is sort of a hacked way, this would be easier to solve using objects.. method BubbleSort(Int[] a)/nested loop grab number 1 enter nest mv <Gnum

Comment: A couple things tho make those arrays outside the loop body